# NodeJs Container Build in Xmcloud Foundation head

Tags: docker, xm-cloud

Trying to work through the xmCloud Foundation head - https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head-staging#deploy-to-xmcloud and install locally using Docker. But getting this error on container build.

```
Step 6/12 : RUN curl.exe -sS -L -o node.zip https://nodejs.org/dist/v%NODEJS_VERSION%/node-v%NODEJS_VERSION%-win-x64.zip
 ---> Running in 76a734f4d2f7
hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 76a734f4d2f7a6afe9a59e9b215037eaa70f324a295141e2a228759f787a2d5a: The request is not supported.
ERROR: Service 'nodejs' failed to build : Build failed
D:\PlayArea\xmCloud\xmcloud-foundation-head-staging\up.ps1 : Container build failed, see errors above
```

Do I need to disable anything specific? I have checked for instances where C:\ is present and changed it to lowercase

Comment: This issue got resolved after lowercasing the C: and restarting the machine

Comment: Didn't work for me ,In what all files have you made changes

Comment: This is not an answer and should be added as a comment under the question. Please remove this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is due to firewall settings and network policy settings on your development machine. Couple of things to try:

- Ensure that the **Use Docker Compose V2** option is not checked and **Use the WSL 2 based engine** is checked in Docker Desktop.
  [image]
- Bypass some common network issues by setting DNS servers in the Docker engine configuration and switching the `buildkit` to `false`

```
{
  "dns": [
    "8.8.8.8"
  ],
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
   "buildkit":false
 }
}
```

[image]

- **DNS Flush on your development machine**: In the command prompt window, type `ipconfig /flushdns` You should see a message confirming that the DNS Resolver Cache was successfully flushed.
- If none of the above options works, install nodejs manually as explained [here](https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2023/02/11/setup-local-xm-cloud-development-environment-using-docker-containers/). Run the set up again.

Answer (score 1):

so after executing multiple commands I was able to fix this issue by executing the command **ipconfig/flushdns**

https://sitecorehelphouse.wordpress.com/2023/02/11/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-nodejs-org/